# Do I use a plural or singular verb after "half"?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, ielts

When we describe a pie chart that gives information about **percentage** of common reasons for travel to a country, which of these two is correct?

> As it is mentioned above, half of visitors *has* a trip for vacation
>
> As it is mentioned above, half of visitors *have* a trip for vacation

Comment: By the way, it would be usual to include a definite article before "visitors". Also, "As it is mentioned above" is not idiomatic. I would recommend this reworded version: "As mentioned above, half of the visitors have a trip for vacation".

Comment: @sumelic thanks.  But as mentioned above.  We are talking about percentage of visitors in the chart. So isn't it a compelling reason to use singularly verb? Because percentage of the passengers is an amount, not number of things

Comment: "Half" of the visitors, even as a percentage, still refers to a group of countable things (visitors) so a plural verb would be natural.

Comment: You could also use “half of all visitors”...

Comment: @a.toraby would you consider migrating your question to ELL, i.e [English Language for Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)? You should become a member,  I think your question would be warmly received, and generate more interest over there. It will be very difficult to reopen  your question on EL&U because the older questions *do* answer the title, but  fail to address the equally important issues that your question raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reword the whole thing and use the past tense because the pie chart reports statistics that *were* accurate when they were recorded.

> As  mentioned previously, **half** of the **visitors** stated that the **trip was** for **pleasure**.

Notice that the term *trip* is in the singular, so the auxiliary  is singular too.

As trips are often categorized as being for pleasure or business, I chose to say *pleasure*   instead of  "vacation".  In fact, the expressions *business trip* and *[pleasure trip](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pleasure-trip)* are idiomatic in English.

If the statistic hovers around 50%,  e.g., 48.9%, 51.2% then use an adverb such as: *approximately*, *nearly*, *almost*, *close to* or *just under/over  half*

> Approximately **50 percent** of all **visitors** stated that their trip to (NAME OF COUNTRY) **was** for a vacation.

Examples found on Google Books

> 1. *Approximately **half the visitors** (53%) had season tickets and just under half (47%) **were** male*
>
> *[Festival and Events Management](https://books.google.it/books?id=FGoABAAAQBAJ&pg=PA320&lpg=PA320&dq=%22just%20under%20half%22%20visitors&source=bl&ots=fYxqF-NEci&sig=d7-3ND_uEeG6HKcZv5zxOdJlFrA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjijufZg4DRAhWK1xQKHSLKDPwQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22just%20under%20half%22%20visitors&f=false)*

Notice that the plural verb agrees with the subject *visitors*

N.B the preposition "of" can be dropped from *half of*, as seen in this example taken from the Bentley University [research](https://www.bentley.edu/files/2016/11/03/2016%20Visitor%20Survey%20-%20web.pdf) survey.

> 2. Ranking second  as a pre-trip influence and representing **over half    the visitors** (53%) reported they also used printed brochures,
>      maps and travel guides to help plan a visit.